# ignore create table from sql dump

Tags: mysql

I have many sql dump files for the same table with different data. I have it saved and the source database has been dropped long back. I have to restore from these dumps, but each dump have `create table` command as well, which fails once table is created. is there a way I can ignore this `create table` command when restoring the dump?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can do something like following:

```
cat /tmp/sample_entity1_490_387 | sed "s/DROP/-- DROP/"|sed "s/CREATE TABLE /CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/"  | mysql -uroot -p entity_restored
```